# Need to Group link buttons in a gridview under a single name.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Gridview in which I have 4 link buttons under a single column. Having this 4 link buttons in gridview directly is increasing the width of the gridview. So I was planning to put all this link buttons under a *single name* and when users hover mouse pointer on *single name* the four links should appear on a modal pop up on which the user clicks to get the required data ..

Example : I have links like .. A B C D in the grid ... I want to put these under a single name LETTERS on hovering the mouse on LETTERS, A B C D should appear on a popup and should be clickable ..

Please help me on this .. I know this can be achieved with Jquery .. Can any one show me the right path ?

Thanks in Advance ..

Answer (score 0):

You can assign common css `class` to link button and use jquery class `selector` to access them.

```
linkbuttons = $('.className');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

**[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/GKfZM/564/)**

You can hover your mouse over `letters` "menu" and then a pop up appears. Check it out!!

Then you have to put the `html` code into your grid.

```
// HTML CODE
<div id="your-dialog-id">
<table>
   <tr> 
       // THE LINKS
       <td><h3>A</h3></td>
       <td><h3>B</h3></td>
       <td><h3>C</h3></td> 
       <td><h3>D</h3></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<p><a href="#" id="open">LETTERS</a></p>​

// JQUERY CODE
$("#open").mouseover(function(){
   $("#your-dialog-id").dialog("open");
});

// This is fired when hover over LETTERS MENU
$("#your-dialog-id").dialog({autoOpen:false,modal: true, title:'letters'});

// This is fired when clic over a single letter
$('h3').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text() + " clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place all link buttons under same TemplateField as shown below

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LETTERS">   
            <ItemTemplate>   
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="A" Text="A" OnClick="A_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>   
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="B" Text="B" OnClick="B_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>    
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="C" Text="C" OnClick="C_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>   
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="D" Text="D" OnClick="D_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>   
            </ItemTemplate>   
        </asp:TemplateField>
```